# Insert default value while creating Table in android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I would like to know how to insert a default value to a table when it's created using Android Sqlite.

Comment: which data type you want to insert?

Comment: TEXT datatype. I need it when creating the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,it uses both text and integer type
replace `MyTableName` with `yourtable`

```
 @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase) { // sqlite oncreate method
        paramSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTableName(_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0,name TEXT DEFAULT 'ram');");
        }
```

Comment: Which error you got?I tested this command on Sqlite browser and its working

Comment: it's not working because probably you've already created this database, try uninstall app/clear app and try again